# Sorting Array Numerical Strings from Highest to Lowest in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I'd like to sort an array of Strings which include both Usernames & Points in the same string from Highest to Lowest, without losing the usernames, how do I do this?

I've tried:

```js
arrayName.sort()
```

However, I have no idea how to make it work with strings! >w<

**Here's what I'm working with:**

```js
let uwu = [
  "hinata:5000",
  "hiro:3000",
  "karuki:6000",
  "arisu: 4000"
]
```

Now I'd like to sort it into a new array, from Highest Points to lowest, like below! >w<

Expected Output:

```js
["karuki:6000", "hinata:5000", "arisu:4000", "hiro:3000"]
```

Please do help me ! Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a helper function that extracts the digits from the string, then call that function on both elements in the sort callback and return the difference:

```js
const input = [
  "hinata:5000",
  "hiro:3000",
  "karuki:6000",
  "arisu: 4000"
];
const getNums = str => str.match(/\d+/)[0];
input.sort((a, b) => getNums(b) - getNums(a));
console.log(input);
```

Comment: Hi! Does this work if the user has numbers in their names?

Comment: No, if that's a possibility, add an end-of-string anchor to the pattern. `\d+$`

Comment: so it'll become ```str.match(/\d+/\d+$)[0]```?

Comment: No, you just need to add an end-of-string anchor. `\d+` becomes `\d+$` - the end-of string anchor was added, nothing else.